# Unity image color changing only in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, firebase-authentication

I basically have this function so I can register a new user to Firebase. The registration is working fine but when the task finishes I would like to give some feedback to the player but I'm having some problems, her's the code:

```
    public void Registration()
{

    Auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("emai2l@gmail.com", "password")
        .ContinueWith((task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Firebase.FirebaseException e =
            task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
            GetAuthError((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
            return;
        }

        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Firebase.FirebaseException e =
            task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
            GetAuthError((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
            return;
        }

        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Color col = Color.red;
            img.color = col; // COLOR CHANGE


            Debug.Log("Registration Complete");                
            return;
        }

    }));
}
```

When async task is completed I'm trying to change the color of an image but it's not working her's a quick video:
https://media.giphy.com/media/fAPTd80taCSq1QRMOd/giphy.gif

PROBLEM:

- Changing image's color in task.IsCompleted the color only changes in the inspector not in the game view
- I tried to use Event.Invoke() and it's not working
- I created a bool and set it to true when task finishes and in Update set the image's color and it was working

Could you help me find a better solution to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: For this, you have only one solution - separate logic from changing views

Comment: I think somewhere else you're creating an instance of the Material. Unity does that whenever you change a property of the Material via the renderer's `material` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a bool property like this (I didn't test it):

```
bool isComplete {
set {
if(isComplete) {
Color col = Color.red;
img.color = col; // COLOR CHANGE
Debug.Log("Registration Complete");
      }
   }
}
```

Set the bool "isComplete" to true in your if statement `(task.isCompleted)`
When the bool is true the color will be changed.

> SOLUTION

So basically to fix the problem I used a Corutine and I wait until the task isCompleted and it's working fine!
Here's the code:

```
   // Button Event
public void OnRegisterUser()
{
    StartCoroutine(Registration("email@google.com", "12345"));
}

private IEnumerator Registration(string email, string password)
{
    // Create Account Async
    var registrationTask = Auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("emaai2dl@gmail.com", "password");
    
    // We wait until the task is Completed
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => registrationTask.IsCompleted);

    // When the task is completed Check for errors
    if(registrationTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseException e =
            registrationTask.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
        
        // Method to see the type of error          
        GetAuthError((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);

        img.color = Color.red;

    }
    
    // Task is Completed
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Registration Completed");
        img.color = Color.green;

    }
}

// Check error type
void GetAuthError(AuthError error)
{
    string msg = "";
    msg = error.ToString();

    switch (error)
    {
        case AuthError.AccountExistsWithDifferentCredentials:
            return;

        case AuthError.MissingPassword:
            return;
        case AuthError.MissingEmail:
            return;
        case AuthError.WrongPassword:
            return;
        case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
            return;
    }

    Debug.LogWarning("Registration(): " + msg);

}
```

Comment: What the main difference from the method that used the @Christian Stamati? It's still async code and this does not solve the problem

Comment: No main difference, @Christian Stamati wrote this in his question "I created a bool and set it to true when task finishes and in Update set the image's color and it was working", so instead of using Update he can try to use a bool property.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for answering, stack overflow's community It's amazing!
I updated the post with the solution! ;)